# What is the second derivative of $e^{(x^y)}$

Tags: derivatives

I need to find the second derivative of $(e^{(x^y)})$. I have tried it using the usual procedure of taking log but couldn't proceed.

Comment: Are you asking, (e(x^y)) or e^(xy)? The brackets makes it seem like you formatted it wrong.

Comment: Its $ e^{x^y}$. Sorry for that.

Comment: So it's $f(x,y)=e^{(x^y)}$, a function of two variables? Do you want the second order partial derivatives?

Comment: It is d^2y/dx^2 ?

Comment: You see, it makes a big difference whether it's $f(x,y)=e^{x^y}$ or whether it's $y=e^{x^y}$. In the second case you would be looking for the implicit derivatives of $y$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: Well, the question was to find the second order partial derivatives of f(x,y)= $ e^{x^y}  with respect to x.

Comment: In that case, you would probably want to use chain rule. $\frac\partial{\partial x}e^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)}\frac\partial{\partial x}g(x)$